# Minimum of function

Tags: functions, optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function with $f(x)=\dfrac{(x^4-2ax^3+3a^2x^2-2a^3x+a^4+9)}{(x^2-ax+a^2)}.$
Determine the minimum of the function, if we know, that $-2\leq a\leq2$, $a\neq0$.

I don't have an idea yet. Do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$f(x)=\frac{(x^2-ax+a^2)^2+9}{x^2-ax+a^2}.$$

Michael